# Thread stuck in Thread.join(), even though other thread has terminated

Tags: java, multithreading, join, jvm

Our Java application starts a worker thread (using `Thread.start()`). Shortly thereafter it calls `Thread.join()` on the worker thread. The worker thread does some stuff and terminates. The first thread exits the call to `join()` and goes on its merry way. Standard stuff:

```
Thread t = new WorkerThread();
t.start();

// Blah blah

t.join();

class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

At least that's how it's supposed to work, and how it does work in any case we can reproduce. We have one customer, however, who is persistently running into trouble.

Looking at the threads using PsiProbe, they see that the worker thread is created. It runs for awhile, but after some time disappears from the list of threads. This happens at an unexpected time (based on timing of other events related to the worker thread). The main thread never gets out of the `join()` call.

This would seem to break `join()`'s contract, and implies to me some sort of JVM-level error. Has anybody witnessed behavior like this, or have any idea what could cause it?

**EDIT 3-3-11:**

I'm still waiting for conclusive data from the customer, but it seems likely that I didn't really know what I thought I knew: the main thread is likely not blocking in `join()` at all, but at a point prior to it.

Thanks to all for the ideas, anyway.

Comment: Well, you did thread.join() not t.join() or did you just mistype?

Comment: I would add logging to worker thread and couple logging statements before/between/after start/join calls. Other solution is to call join with timeout ( join(long millis) ). That could solve issue even if there is JVM level error.

Comment: What version of Java (patch level) and what platform is your client seeing this on?

Comment: @dontocsata Yeah, just mis-typed; will fix, thanks.

Comment: @Stephen C - Now that it's becoming apparent that this could be a JVM issue, I'll need to get specifics of the version. It's running under JBoss AS 4.2.3 (I think), if that that might matter.

Comment: @Petro I'd love to get some targeted logging in there, but there's pretty limited opportunity to get them running a new release in the short term.

Comment: Gotcha. Then you could ask them to use jstack tool  (supplied with JDK) instead of PsiProbe. It will give you stacktraces of running threads. There is a chance that PsiProbe itself has a bug and doesn't display 'running' thread properly.

Comment: @Stephen C, I dont believe the JVM bug theory :)

Comment: @Aron, show the stack trace showed by jstack (as  Petro Semeniuk suggests). Also possible, through JBoss jmx-consoles (usually http: //host/jmx-console), jboss.system/type=ServerInfo and click listThreadDump; [Forgot: if you have some synchronization by ThreadGroup, the thread cannot exit, although this is unlikely]

Comment: @bestsss - frankly, neither do I.  But there's little convincing evidence either way.

Comment: @Stephen C, there could be some other reasons like `synchronized(t) {. block on something..}`, this prevents join since it also uses sync(t). W/o the stack trace the issue cannot be resolved.

Comment: ..The idea (`sync(t)`)is slightly supported b/c of the subclassing of Thread, i.e. `this` ref is widely available (compared to just runnable). So there could be an escaping `this` and further sync.

Comment: @bestss - But why would only one customer be experiencing these problems?  Like I said, we have only theories, and no convincing evidence.

Comment: @bestsss - I wasn't aware of the ability to dump thread stacks via jmx-console; that will be convenient for the customer to do. I'll ask them to do it today.

Comment: @Stephen C, some IO particularly blocking on the user/network/jgroups/clustered jndi/database.. could be a lot of stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search of the [Java Bugs Database](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/) didn't throw up anything that matches your symptoms.  But it would be worth your while doing a more extensive search.

---

However, it is worth noting that a JVM bug is only one of many possible theories (see the comments), and there is very little evidence for any theory at this stage.  If I were you, I would:

1. figured out what the customer's platform is
2. do a search of the Java bugs database for any known bugs that seem to match the observed symptoms (such as they are).
3. if you find a bug that looks like a "hit", evaluate it further, try to confirm that it is really the customer's problem, and see if there are any ways to mitigate it.
4. in addition ...

   - look at the other possible theories; e.g. see above
   - try and figure out what is different about the customer's installation compared with others who don't have this problem
   - add more monitoring, and try to get the customer to use that version.

(On the last bullet point, it may be necessary to point out the obvious to the customer.  If they want the bug fixed, they may need to do extra stuff to help you track down the bug, like installing running an "experimental" version of the application for a bit.)